# Manipulating a Button's link in JS

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink, addeventlistener, getelementsbyclassname

I am attempting to manipulate the hyperlink of a button and I'm getting nowhere with this and not sure where I am going wrong.

The Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.site.td/Calendar.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.site.td/Calendar.js"></script>
<div id="the-calendar"></div>
<script>
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   var options = {
   fullNames : false
   };
   var myCalendar = new Calendar(document.getElementById('the-calendar'), options);
   });
</script>
```

This generates an event calendar that is loaded on a separate website. It works perfectly when loading it on a separate domain except for one thing. There is a more info button for events and when you click that it attempts to go to:

```
/folder/folder/folder/event-name-1
```

So of course, when I generate it on a separate domain it attempts that same folder path except with the current domain. Therefore it goes nowhere since the folders are not the same on both domains.

I want to add an onClick event to the button to manipulate the path of the hyperlink.

The button is:

```
<button class="calendar-icon-info-action">More info</button>
```

Keep in mind this button is not generated until the initial script above loads and populates the page with the HTML for the calendar.

So once the calendar is loaded, I need each more info link for each event to be manipulated to add the original domain path. I would need a variable to store the original path because that will not change too.

So to recap more info leads generates:

```
/folder/folder/folder/event-name-1
```

I want this stored in a variable and then another var for the domain stored together so it becomes something like this:

```
var a = "domain.tld";
var b = "/folder/folder/folder/event-name-1";
var c = a + b;

document.getElementsByClassName("calendar-icon-info-action")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementsByClassName("calendar-icon-info-action")[0].href = var c;
});
```

Comment: Yes the button is dynamically generated, and yes I have the link to the calendar.js file but it cannot be modified its thru a third-party vendor providing a service for the website and they willl not modify their js file to fix this because of how it is written.

Answer (score 0):

The `href` attribute is applicable only for a tags (links). Since you have a `<button>`, what you could do is intercept and block the original event, and redirect the page to the desired URL.

Something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("calendar-icon-info-action")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event){
    // This will stop the original event:
    event.preventDefault();

    // This will open your desired URL:
    window.location.href = c
});
```

If you have multiple buttons and want to update the event of all of them, you could loop the buttons:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".calendar-icon-info-action").forEach((elem) => elem.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = c;
}))
```

---

For future reference, if you had links instead of buttons, and wanted to change the `href` attribute, the proper way to do is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("calendar-icon-info-action")[0].setAttribute('href', 'your-url-here')
```

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. I wasn't specific enough, and I was wrong by doing the var a,b,c in initial explanation. The 'your-url' is dynamically created when originally clicked. So there is no way for the script to know what the variable or 'your-url' would be until it is clicked.  I guess what i really need is 'href' somehow injected before the 'your-url' once it is dynamically created upon click?  And yes there are multiple links on the page so each 'your-url' would be different.

Comment: I am a little confuse...first, are you dealing with `<buttons>` or `<a>` tags? `href` are only for `<a>`

Comment: And you mentioned the links are dynamic. So do you want to prepend something to the link? (since you don't know what the link should be)

Comment: the calendar.js file creates a calendar in html and the js listener above pulls the events from the other website. The events have a div class button labeled more info. All of it is dynamically populated on the page so yes there is no way to pre-determine the link. So yes, to your last comment I need a way to prepend or insert the domain.tld before the dynamically generated hyperlink.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible then. The problem is, a button is just a clickable element, it doesn't contain any hyperlink information. So, unless those generated links are visible in the code, you will never be able to retrieve them using Javascript. Do you have more code that you can share? Maybe the calendar.js or the final generated dynamic code? That may give us a clue, but I am afraid this is an impossible task...